# Why nuxt3 empty application not running for the first time?

Tags: server, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Im using npx nuxi init  To initialize a new nuxt application, then npm install all the dependence, and run npm run dev, the browser open but the application dont work, i got an 503 error (server unavailable ) and i didn’t found any similar error.
What can i do start a new empty nuxt 3 application?

[image]

Comment: What is your node version? Did you followed this guide? https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/quick-start Do you have any additional errors/warnings?

Comment: Yes, i did everything as described at their website, still always same error

Comment: Do you have a github repo?

Comment: @kissu yes, https://github.com/danielronen/Nuxt3_example

Comment: Loading perfectly fine on my side. What are your versions of Node, yarn and what is your OS?

Comment: OS is windows 11,  everything is LTS version!

Comment: Oh yeah, Nuxt3 may have some issues on Windows, check their discussions/issues. I do run UNIX so I have none of those issues.